# SQL how to add all fields with the same field value and order it by descending order

Tags: sql

I want to add and know the total of all field2 with the same field1 value and order it by descending order

I tried doing this but it says paramater stuff.

```
SELECT field1, SUM(field2) AS total 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY field1 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: You didn't tell us which DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ..) but I'm 100% certain that whatever you use "*paramater stuff*" is **not** a valid error message. So please show us the complete and exact error message and include which DBMS you are using. It is valid SQL though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c989/1

Comment: @user3260151 even it is answered this is a valid code i think, what's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT   field1, SUM(field2) AS total 
FROM     table1 
GROUP BY field1 
ORDER BY SUM(field2) DESC
```

Comment: Using the alias in the `ORDER BY` is valid SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c989/1

Comment: I tried using ORDER BY SUM(field2) DESC and it works while the ORDER BY total DESC doesn't work I'm using access SQL.